# GitHub Actions: [Error] : Unexpected value 'with'

Tags: github, github-actions

Next code leads to the error: "Unexpected value 'with'"

```yaml
  build-flatpak:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/build_package_flatpack.yml
    needs:
      - release
      - build
    secrets: inherit
    with:
      version: ${{ needs.release.outputs.version }}
      sha: ${{ github.sha }}
      upload_url: ${{ needs.release.outputs.upload_url }}
      is_release: true
```

While the step before works fine:

```yaml
jobs:
  release:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/create_release_page.yml
    secrets: inherit
    with:
      draft: false
```

What might be wrong with the first one?

Full pipeline: https://github.com/lyskouski/app-finance/blob/main/.github/workflows/build.yml

P.S. Both of nested scenarios use:

```yaml
on:
  workflow_call:
```

Comment: The error may be related to the `build_package_flatpak` reusable workflow you created, at the [line 46](https://github.com/lyskouski/app-finance/blob/791929cb974e21f725daede8ea7cb5e5ee99a310/.github/workflows/build_package_flatpak.yml#L46). This `with` syntax doesn't seem related to any step.

Comment: @GuiFalourd: That's related to the step it's under but that step also has `run` too. Both `run` and `with` cannot be used in the same step hence the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @GuiFalourd! May you put it as a comment to close ticket? Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Unexpected value 'with'` error message on Github UI isn't very clear as it doesn't refer to the file impacted, which make it harder to troubleshoot.

Checking your repository, I observed the error is actually related to the `build_package_flatpak` reusable workflow you created, at the [line 46](https://github.com/lyskouski/app-finance/blob/791929cb974e21f725daede8ea7cb5e5ee99a310/.github/workflows/build_package_flatpak.yml#L46), and not related to the `build.yaml` workflow you shared.

**Removing this field on the reusable workflow should resolve your issue.**

*Note: As [@Azeem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7670262/azeem) highlighted in the comment above, a `run` step isn't compatible with the `with` field, they cannot be used in the same step, which hence the error.*